# Knapsack problem where there are three arrays: weight of an item array, value of an item array and amount of an item array

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

What would be the solution to this problem? I think it would be rather tricky because you would have to juggle three characteristics.

Here is my attempt:
p-value, s-weight, k-amount, max-maximum weight,

m-number of items to take

static int solution(int[] s, int[] p, int[] k, int max)
        {

```
        int[,] matrix = new int[s.Length + 1, max + 1];

        for (int i = 1; i <= s.Length; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j <= max; j++)
            {                    

                int m = 1;
                for(int z = k[i - 1]; z > 0; z--)
                {
                    if(z * s[i - 1] <= j)
                    {                            
                        m = z;
                        break;

                    }
                }                    

                if (s[i - 1] * m <= j)
                {
                    matrix[i, j] =
                        Math.Max((p[i - 1] * m) + matrix[i - 1, j - s[i - 1] * m],
                    matrix[i - 1, j]);
                }
                else
                {
                    matrix[i, j] = matrix[i - 1, j];
                }

            }
        }

        return matrix[s.Length, max];
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

For knapsack with some amount of item copies there's a nice trick to reduce it to classical knapsack:

1. Let's say we have `x` copies of some item weighting `w` and giving value `v`
2. Notice that it's the same as having `log x` items where each item has `w`, `2*w`, `4*w`, ... weight and `v`, `2*v`, `4*v`value and sum of all weights is same as `w*x`
3. In cases where `x` can't be expressed as sum of powers of 2 we can make last number what's left (i.e. if `x=10`, our weight distribution is: `1 + 2 + 4 + 3 = 10`). The important thing is to choose such weights that all possible pickings of `1..x` are possible to make by picking some subset

After this the problem is reduced to classical knapsack.

Complexity `O(#items * #maxWeight * log2(#MaxItemCount)`

Answer (score 0):

We can make the dp matrix using the weight array and the amount array.
For the amount array take the max of it (assume `K`), then make the dp matrix.

`dp[n+1][k+1]` gives the minimum cost to satisfy a person with capacity `k` who can eat the first `n` dishes (where `n` is the size of the weight array and `k` is the max amount a person can eat)

the relation afterward will be the same as an unbounded knapsack.